# Serialize those fields which are filled or selected

Tags: jquery, serialization

I want to **serialize** those fields which are **filled** or **selected** included (**textboxes**, **checkboxes** and **selectmenu**).

**HTML Section**

```
<div id="all_field_0">
   <input type="text" name="a_0"/>
   <input type="text" name="b_0"/>
   <select name="c_0">
     <option value="1">a</option>
     <option value="2">b</option>
     <option value="3">c</option>
   </select>
   <select name="d_0">
     <option value="1">a</option>
     <option value="2">b</option>
     <option value="3">c</option>
   </select>
</div>

<div id="all_field_1">
   <input type="text" name="a_1"/>
   <input type="text" name="b_1"/>
   <select name="c_1">
     <option value="1">a</option>
     <option value="2">b</option>
     <option value="3">c</option>
   </select>
   <select name="d_1">
     <option value="1">a</option>
     <option value="2">b</option>
     <option value="3">c</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

**jQuery Section**

This code serialize all fields

```
var field_div = "";
for(var fc=0; fc<2; fc++)
{
  field_div = "#all_field_"+fc;
  $(field_div + " :input,select").serializeObject()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below script seems to satisfy what your looking for. Each field just needs a bit of logic to see if values have been entered. Input and select work like you originally selected them but the check box needs 1 more piece of logic.

```
var field_div = "";
for(var fc=0; fc<2; fc++)
{
  field_div = "#all_field_"+fc;

  //Check to see if input has value
  if($(field_div + " :input,select").val()) {
    //Field has something
    $(field_div + " :input,select").serializeObject(); //Serialize and store somewhere
  } else {
    //Field doesn't have something
  }

  //Check for selected checkbox
  if($(field_div + " :checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
     //Checkbox is checked
     $(field_div + " :checkbox:").serializeObject(); //Serialize and store somewhere
  } else {
     //Checkbox is not checked
  }

}
```

Comment: Really a nice logic but it doesn't work because when you entered in IF statement It will serialize all fields of div. I tried for checkbox like this, $(fieldname+"input:checkbox:checked").serializeObject(); It is working.